# Grails Spring Security Plugin - Custom Login and Logout URL, Controller, and GSP

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, gsp

We have several in-house developed application in Groovy/Grails and use a shared plugin containing code that is common to all applications.  We're needing more advanced authentication (LDAP, CAS, etc.) so it's time to implement the Spring Security plugin.  I've been doing a bunch of reading on it, but I'm stuck at something as simple as changing the URLs and GSP pages that are used for the login and logout.  I'm assuming that we'll also need a custom controller to make these changes.

In a normal situation where an application is using the Spring Security plugin, changing the default controller and/or GSPs seems to be as easy as just creating a file with the same name and location as the original files (since application files override plugin files).  However, we're including the Spring Security plugin in our shared plugin which then is included in the application ... so unless it's possible to have one plugin override another plugins files this sort of solution doesn't seem to work here.

What would be the correct approach for overriding the default login/logout pages, url, and possibly controllers being used?

Answer (score 2):

The `controllers` and `GSPs` are part of the plugin in `2.0`. If you want to customize them **copy** them from the installed plugin directory to your project in the **same folders** and make the changes there. App files always override plugin files because the plugins are compiled first, then the app, so the app's files take precedence.

This procedure worked successfully for me.

Comment: Thanks, however, like mentioned in my question this doesn't work for me since I'm including the Spring Security plugin in a shared plugin which then is included in various applications.  I need to provide this custom functionality in our shared plugin.

Comment: What's the path to the "installed plugin directory" ?